# Проблема с PickerView

Tags: ios, iphone

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ListProc : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *m_pPickerView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *m_val1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *m_val2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *m_resText;
    IBOutlet UILabel *m_res;
    IBOutlet NSString *m_text;
}
@property(retain,nonatomic) UITextField *m_val1;
@property(retain,nonatomic) UITextField *m_val2;
@property(retain,nonatomic) UILabel *m_resText;
@property(retain,nonatomic) UILabel *m_res;
@property(retain,nonatomic) UIPickerView *m_pPickerView;
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSString *m_text;
-(IBAction)onTextChanged:(id)sender;
@end
```

ListProc.m

```
#import "ListProc.h"

@implementation ListProc
@synthesize m_pPickerView;
@synthesize m_res;
@synthesize m_val1;
@synthesize m_val2;
@synthesize m_resText;
@synthesize m_text;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 10;
}

-(void) CalcAll
{

    if((m_text.length > 0) && (m_val1.hasText) && (m_val2.hasText))
    {
        float massa;
        if(m_text == @"6")
            massa = 0.222;
        else if(m_text == @"8")
            massa = 0.395;
        else if(m_text == @"10")
            massa = 0.617;
        else if(m_text == @"12")
            massa = 0.888;
        else if(m_text == @"14")
            massa = 1.21;
        else if(m_text == @"16")
            massa = 1.58;
        else if(m_text == @"18")
            massa = 2;
        else if(m_text == @"20")
            massa = 2.47;
        else if(m_text == @"22")
            massa = 2.98;
        else if(m_text == @"25")
            massa = 3.85;
        else if(m_text == @"28")
            massa = 4.83;
        else if(m_text == @"32")
            massa = 6.31;
        else if(m_text == @"36")
            massa = 7.99;
        else if(m_text == @"40")
            massa = 9.87;
        else if(m_text == @"45")
            massa = 12.48;
        else if(m_text == @"50")
            massa = 15.41;
        else if(m_text == @"55")
            massa = 18.65;
        else if(m_text == @"60")
            massa = 22.19;

        int val1 = [m_val1.text intValue];
        int val2 = [m_val2.text intValue];
        float res = val1 * val2 * massa;
        m_resText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", res];
    }
}
-(IBAction)onTextChanged:(id)sender
{
        [self CalcAll];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *text = [self pickerView:m_pPickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:component];
    m_text = text;
    [self CalcAll];

}

-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView*)thePickerView
                        titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"6",@"8",@"10",@"12",@"14",@"16",@"18",@"20",@"22",@"25",nil ];
        return [data objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView
{
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Проблема в том что когда начинаю изменять значения в пикере приложене останавливается и ругется на строку
if((m_text.length > 0) && (m_val1.hasText) && (m_val2.hasText))

Comment: Просто оно не в настроении, попробуйте попозже еще раз, или цветов ему купите, а можно еще и написать нам на что и как ругается, и кто такие m_val{1,2} тоже интересно...

Comment: добавил .h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread 1: stopped at breakpoint 1
Это же вообще не ошибка.
Зайди во вкладку breakpoints и удали его.

Comment: Скорей всего Define прав, просто "кто то" выставил брэйкпоинт и забыл про него)))

Comment: Вся фишка в том, что это скорее всего невидимый брейкпоинт, по крайнее мере у меня такие иногда появляются и в икскоде, и в вижуал студии, и в билдере.

Comment: Да спасибо. Верно - откуда он там взялся понятия не имею.

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSString stringWithString:[data objectAtIndex:row]];
```

Comment: все также(

Comment: m_text не nil? и память для него выделяется, я вижу что создается локальная переменная, которя потом удаляется

Comment: не nil....

Comment: NSString *text = [self pickerView:m_pPickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:component];
    m_text = text;

поменять на
m_text=[NSString stringWithString:[self pickerView:m_pPickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:component]];

А если нет, то я не знаю.

Comment: неа(( опять там же стопится

Comment: А что пишет то хоть?

Answer (score 0):

А что за методы hasText? У UITextField'a таких нет. Чтобы проверить наличие текста в текстфилде используйте что-то вроде

```
[[m_val1 text] length]
```

Comment: Заменил но проблема осталась

Comment: какая проблема? на что жалуется? вы можете дать больше информации

Comment: Thread 1: stopped at breakpoint 1  и указывет на строку с проверками (вылезает когда я начинаю листать пикер)

Comment: Что пишет отладчик во время остановки на breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите еще на всякий случай в .h файле делегейты для TextField(**UITextFieldDelegate**)  и попробуйте делать проверку с текст филдов на **nil** или на **Length != 0**